# DataDog GKE NESTJS integration using DataDog's helm chart

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, datadog

Im trying to deploy my service and read my local logfile from the inside pod.

Using DataDog's helm chart values with the following configs :

```
## Default values for Datadog Agent
## See Datadog helm documentation to learn more:
## https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/kubernetes/helm/

## @param image - object - required
## Define the Datadog image to work with.
#
image:

  ## @param repository - string - required
  ## Define the repository to use:
  ## use "datadog/agent" for Datadog Agent 6
  ## use "datadog/dogstatsd" for Standalone Datadog Agent DogStatsD6
  #
  repository: datadog/agent

  ## @param tag - string - required
  ## Define the Agent version to use.
  ## Use 6.13.0-jmx to enable jmx fetch collection
  #
  tag: 6.13.0

  ## @param pullPolicy - string - required
  ## The Kubernetes pull policy.
  #
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent

  ## @param pullSecrets - list of key:value strings - optional
  ## It is possible to specify docker registry credentials
  ## See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#specifying-imagepullsecrets-on-a-pod
  #
  # pullSecrets:
  #   - name: "<REG_SECRET>"

nameOverride: ""
fullnameOverride: ""

datadog:

  ## @param apiKey - string - required
  ## Set this to your Datadog API key before the Agent runs.
  ## ref: https://app.datadoghq.com/account/settings#agent/kubernetes
  #
  apiKey: "xxxxxxxx"

  ## @param apiKeyExistingSecret - string - optional
  ## Use existing Secret which stores API key instead of creating a new one.
  ## If set, this parameter takes precedence over "apiKey".
  #
  # apiKeyExistingSecret: <DATADOG_API_KEY_SECRET>

  ## @param appKey - string - optional
  ## If you are using clusterAgent.metricsProvider.enabled = true, you must set
  ## a Datadog application key for read access to your metrics.
  #
  appKey: "xxxxxx"

  ## @param appKeyExistingSecret - string - optional
  ## Use existing Secret which stores APP key instead of creating a new one
  ## If set, this parameter takes precedence over "appKey".
  #
  # appKeyExistingSecret: <DATADOG_APP_KEY_SECRET>

  ## @param securityContext - object - optional
  ## You can modify the security context used to run the containers by
  ## modifying the label type below:
  #
  # securityContext:
  #   seLinuxOptions:
  #     seLinuxLabel: "spc_t"

  ## @param clusterName - string - optional
  ## Set a unique cluster name to allow scoping hosts and Cluster Checks easily
  #
  # clusterName: <CLUSTER_NAME>

  ## @param name - string - required
  ## Daemonset/Deployment container name
  ## See clusterAgent.containerName if clusterAgent.enabled = true
  #
  name: datadog

  ## @param site - string - optional - default: 'datadoghq.com'
  ## The site of the Datadog intake to send Agent data to.
  ## Set to 'datadoghq.eu' to send data to the EU site.
  #
  # site: datadoghq.com

  ## @param dd_url - string - optional - default: 'https://app.datadoghq.com'
  ## The host of the Datadog intake server to send Agent data to, only set this option
  ## if you need the Agent to send data to a custom URL.
  ## Overrides the site setting defined in "site".
  #
  # dd_url: https://app.datadoghq.com

  ## @param logLevel - string - required
  ## Set logging verbosity, valid log levels are:
  ## trace, debug, info, warn, error, critical, and off
  #
  logLevel: INFO

  ## @param podLabelsAsTags - list of key:value strings - optional
  ## Provide a mapping of Kubernetes Labels to Datadog Tags.
  #
  # podLabelsAsTags:
  #   app: kube_app
  #   release: helm_release
  #   <KUBERNETES_LABEL>: <DATADOG_TAG_KEY>

  ## @param podAnnotationsAsTags - list of key:value strings - optional
  ## Provide a mapping of Kubernetes Annotations to Datadog Tags
  #
  # podAnnotationsAsTags:
  #   iam.amazonaws.com/role: kube_iamrole
  #   <KUBERNETES_ANNOTATIONS>: <DATADOG_TAG_KEY>

  ## @param tags  - list of key:value elements - optional
  ## List of tags to attach to every metric, event and service check collected by this Agent.
  ##
  ## Learn more about tagging: https://docs.datadoghq.com/tagging/
  #
  # tags:
  #   - <KEY_1>:<VALUE_1>
  #   - <KEY_2>:<VALUE_2>

  ## @param useCriSocketVolume - boolean - required
  ## Enable container runtime socket volume mounting
  #
  useCriSocketVolume: true

  ## @param dogstatsdOriginDetection - boolean - optional
  ## Enable origin detection for container tagging
  ## https://docs.datadoghq.com/developers/dogstatsd/unix_socket/#using-origin-detection-for-container-tagging
  #
  # dogstatsdOriginDetection: true

  ## @param useDogStatsDSocketVolume - boolean - optional
  ## Enable dogstatsd over Unix Domain Socket
  ## ref: https://docs.datadoghq.com/developers/dogstatsd/unix_socket/
  #
  # useDogStatsDSocketVolume: true

  ## @param nonLocalTraffic - boolean - optional - default: false
  ## Enable this to make each node accept non-local statsd traffic.
  ## ref: https://github.com/DataDog/docker-dd-agent#environment-variables
  #
  nonLocalTraffic: true

  ## @param collectEvents - boolean - optional - default: false
  ## Enables this to start event collection from the kubernetes API
  ## ref: https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/kubernetes/event_collection/
  #
  collectEvents: true

  ## @param leaderElection - boolean - optional - default: false
  ## Enables leader election mechanism for event collection.
  #
  # leaderElection: false

  ## @param leaderLeaseDuration - integer - optional - default: 60
  ## Set the lease time for leader election in second.
  #
  # leaderLeaseDuration: 60

  ## @param logsEnabled - boolean - optional - default: false
  ## Enables this to activate Datadog Agent log collection.
  ## ref: https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/basic_agent_usage/kubernetes/#log-collection-setup
  #
  logsEnabled: true

  ## @param logsConfigContainerCollectAll - boolean - optional - default: false
  ## Enable this to allow log collection for all containers.
  ## ref: https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/basic_agent_usage/kubernetes/#log-collection-setup
  #
  logsConfigContainerCollectAll: true

  ## @param containerLogsPath - string - optional - default: /var/lib/docker/containers
  ## This to allow log collection from container log path. Set to a different path if not
  ## using docker runtime.
  ## ref: https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/kubernetes/daemonset_setup/?tab=k8sfile#create-manifest
  #
  containerLogsPath: /var/lib/docker/containers


  ## @param apmEnabled - boolean - optional - default: false
  ## Enable this to enable APM and tracing, on port 8126
  ## ref: https://github.com/DataDog/docker-dd-agent#tracing-from-the-host
  #
  apmEnabled: true

  ## @param processAgentEnabled - boolean - optional - default: false
  ## Enable this to activate live process monitoring.
  ## Note: /etc/passwd is automatically mounted to allow username resolution.
  ## ref: https://docs.datadoghq.com/graphing/infrastructure/process/#kubernetes-daemonset
  #
  processAgentEnabled: true

  ## @param env - list of object - optional
  ## The dd-agent supports many environment variables
  ## ref: https://github.com/DataDog/datadog-agent/tree/master/Dockerfiles/agent#environment-variables
  #
  # env:
  #   - name: <ENV_VAR_NAME>
  #     value: <ENV_VAR_VALUE>

  ## @param volumes - list of objects - optional
  ## Specify additional volumes to mount in the dd-agent container
  #
  # volumes:
  #   - hostPath:
  #     path: <HOST_PATH>
  #     name: <VOLUME_NAME>

  ## @param volumeMounts - list of objects - optional
  ## Specify additional volumes to mount in the dd-agent container
  #
  # volumeMounts:
  #   - name: <VOLUME_NAME>
  #     mountPath: <CONTAINER_PATH>
  #     readOnly: true

  ## @param confd - list of objects - optional
  ## Provide additional check configurations (static and Autodiscovery)
  ## Each key becomes a file in /conf.d
  ## ref: https://github.com/DataDog/datadog-agent/tree/master/Dockerfiles/agent#optional-volumes
  ## ref: https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/autodiscovery/
  #
  confd:
    conf.yaml: |-
      init_config:
      instances:
      logs:
        - type: "file"
          path: "/app/logs/service.log"
          service: nodejs
          source: nodejs
          sourcecategory: sourcecode
  #   kubernetes_state.yaml: |-
  #     ad_identifiers:
  #       - kube-state-metrics
  #     init_config:
  #     instances:
  #       - kube_state_url: http://%%host%%:8080/metrics

  ## @param checksd - list of key:value strings - optional
  ## Provide additional custom checks as python code
  ## Each key becomes a file in /checks.d
  ## ref: https://github.com/DataDog/datadog-agent/tree/master/Dockerfiles/agent#optional-volumes
  #
  # checksd:
  #   service.py: |-

  ## @param criSocketPath - string - optional
  ## Path to the container runtime socket (if different from Docker)
  ## This is supported starting from agent 6.6.0
  #
  # criSocketPath: /var/run/containerd/containerd.sock

  ## @param dogStatsDSocketPath - string - optional
  ## Path to the DogStatsD socket
  #
  # dogStatsDSocketPath: /var/run/datadog/dsd.socket

  ## @param livenessProbe - object - optional
  ## Override the agent's liveness probe logic from the default:
  ## In case of issues with the probe, you can disable it with the
  ## following values, to allow easier investigating:
  #
  # livenessProbe:
  #   exec:
  #     command: ["/bin/true"]

  ## @param resources - object -required
  ## datadog-agent resource requests and limits
  ## Make sure to keep requests and limits equal to keep the pods in the Guaranteed QoS class
  ## Ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/compute-resources/
  #
  resources: {}
  # requests:
  #   cpu: 200m
  #   memory: 256Mi
  # limits:
  #   cpu: 200m
  #   memory: 256Mi

## @param clusterAgent - object - required
## This is the Datadog Cluster Agent implementation that handles cluster-wide
## metrics more cleanly, separates concerns for better rbac, and implements
## the external metrics API so you can autoscale HPAs based on datadog metrics
## ref: https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/kubernetes/cluster/
#
clusterAgent:

  ## @param enabled - boolean - required
  ## Set this to true to enable Datadog Cluster Agent
  #
  enabled: false

  containerName: cluster-agent
  image:
    repository: datadog/cluster-agent
    tag: 1.3.2
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent

  ## @param token - string - required
  ## This needs to be at least 32 characters a-zA-z
  ## It is a preshared key between the node agents and the cluster agent
  ## ref:
  #
  token: ""

  replicas: 1

  ## @param metricsProvider - object - required
  ## Enable the metricsProvider to be able to scale based on metrics in Datadog
  #
  metricsProvider:
    enabled: true

  ## @param clusterChecks - object - required
  ## Enable the Cluster Checks feature on both the cluster-agents and the daemonset
  ## ref: https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/autodiscovery/clusterchecks/
  ## Autodiscovery via Kube Service annotations is automatically enabled
  #
  clusterChecks:
    enabled: true

  ## @param confd - list of objects - optional
  ## Provide additional cluster check configurations
  ## Each key will become a file in /conf.d
  ## ref: https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/autodiscovery/
  #
  # confd:
  #   mysql.yaml: |-
  #     cluster_check: true
  #     instances:
  #       - server: '<EXTERNAL_IP>'
  #         port: 3306
  #         user: datadog
  #         pass: '<YOUR_CHOSEN_PASSWORD>'

  ## @param resources - object -required
  ## Datadog cluster-agent resource requests and limits.
  #
  resources: {}
#    requests:
#      cpu: 200m
#      memory: 256Mi
#    limits:
#      cpu: 200m
#      memory: 256Mi

  ## @param priorityclassName - string - optional
  ## Name of the priorityClass to apply to the Cluster Agent

  # priorityClassName: system-cluster-critical

  ## @param livenessProbe - object - optional
  ## Override the agent's liveness probe logic from the default:
  ## In case of issues with the probe, you can disable it with the
  ## following values, to allow easier investigating:
  #
  # livenessProbe:
  #   exec:
  #     command: ["/bin/true"]

  ## @param podAnnotations - list of key:value strings - optional
  ## Annotations to add to the cluster-agents's pod(s)
  #
  # podAnnotations:
  #   key: "value"

  ## @param readinessProbe - object - optional
  ## Override the cluster-agent's readiness probe logic from the default:
  #
  # readinessProbe:

rbac:

  ## @param created - boolean - required
  ## If true, create & use RBAC resources
  #
  create: true

  ## @param serviceAccountName - string - required
  ## Ignored if rbac.create is true
  #
  serviceAccountName: default

tolerations: []

kubeStateMetrics:

  ## @param enabled - boolean - required
  ## If true, deploys the kube-state-metrics deployment.
  ## ref: https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/stable/kube-state-metrics
  #
  enabled: true

kube-state-metrics:
  rbac:
    ## @param created - boolean - required
    ## If true, create & use RBAC resources
    #
    create: true

  serviceAccount:
    ## @param created - boolean - required
    ## If true, create ServiceAccount, require rbac kube-state-metrics.rbac.create true
    #
    create: true
    ## @param name - string - required
    ## The name of the ServiceAccount to use.
    ## If not set and create is true, a name is generated using the fullname template
    #
    name: coupon-service-account

  ## @param resources - object - optional
  ## Resource requests and limits for the kube-state-metrics container.
  #
  # resources:
  #   requests:
  #     cpu: 200m
  #     memory: 256Mi
  #   limits:
  #     cpu: 200m
  #     memory: 256Mi

daemonset:

  ## @param enabled - boolean - required
  ## You should keep Datadog DaemonSet enabled!
  ## The exceptional case could be a situation when you need to run
  ## single DataDog pod per every namespace, but you do not need to
  ## re-create a DaemonSet for every non-default namespace install.
  ## Note: StatsD and DogStatsD work over UDP, so you may not
  ## get guaranteed delivery of the metrics in Datadog-per-namespace setup!
  #
  enabled: true

  ## @param useDedicatedContainers - boolean - optional
  ## Deploy each datadog agent process in a separate container. Allow fine-grained
  ## control over allocated resources and better isolation.
  #
  # useDedicatedContainers: false

  containers:

    agent:
      ## @param env - list - required
      ## Additionnal environment variables for the agent container.
      #
      # env:

      ## @param logLevel - string - optional
      ## Set logging verbosity, valid log levels are:
      ## trace, debug, info, warn, error, critical, and off.
      ## If not set, fall back to the value of datadog.logLevel.
      #
      logLevel: INFO

      ## @param resources - object - required
      ## Resource requests and limits for the agent container.
      #
      resources: 
       requests:
         cpu: 200m
         memory: 256Mi
       limits:
         cpu: 200m
         memory: 256Mi

    processAgent:
      ## @param env - list - required
      ## Additionnal environment variables for the process-agent container.
      #
      # env:

      ## @param logLevel - string - optional
      ## Set logging verbosity, valid log levels are:
      ## trace, debug, info, warn, error, critical, and off.
      ## If not set, fall back to the value of datadog.logLevel.
      #
      logLevel: INFO

      ## @param resources - object - required
      ## Resource requests and limits for the process-agent container.
      #
      resources: 
       requests:
         cpu: 100m
         memory: 200Mi
       limits:
         cpu: 100m
         memory: 200Mi

    traceAgent:
      ## @param env - list - required
      ## Additionnal environment variables for the trace-agent container.
      #
      # env:

      ## @param logLevel - string - optional
      ## Set logging verbosity, valid log levels are:
      ## trace, debug, info, warn, error, critical, and off.
      ## If not set, fall back to the value of datadog.logLevel.
      #
      logLevel: INFO

      ## @param resources - object - required
      ## Resource requests and limits for the trace-agent container.
      #
      resources: 
       requests:
         cpu: 100m
         memory: 200Mi
       limits:
         cpu: 100m
         memory: 200Mi

  ## @param useHostNetwork - boolean - optional
  ## Bind ports on the hostNetwork. Useful for CNI networking where hostPort might
  ## not be supported. The ports need to be available on all hosts. It Can be
  ## used for custom metrics instead of a service endpoint.
  ##
  ## WARNING: Make sure that hosts using this are properly firewalled otherwise
  ## metrics and traces are accepted from any host able to connect to this host.
  #
  useHostNetwork: true

  ## @param useHostPort - boolean - optional
  ## Sets the hostPort to the same value of the container port. Needs to be used
  ## to receive traces in a standard APM set up. Can be used as for sending custom metrics.
  ## The ports need to be available on all hosts.
  ##
  ## WARNING: Make sure that hosts using this are properly firewalled otherwise
  ## metrics and traces are accepted from any host able to connect to this host.
  #
  useHostPort: true

  ## @param useHostPID - boolean - optional
  ## Run the agent in the host's PID namespace. This is required for Dogstatsd origin
  ## detection to work. See https://docs.datadoghq.com/developers/dogstatsd/unix_socket/
  #
  # useHostPID: true

  ## @param podAnnotations - list of key:value strings - optional
  ## Annotations to add to the DaemonSet's Pods
  #
  # podAnnotations:
  #   <POD_ANNOTATION>: '[{"key": "<KEY>", "value": "<VALUE>"}]'

  ## @param tolerations - array - optional
  ## Allow the DaemonSet to schedule on tainted nodes (requires Kubernetes >= 1.6)
  #
  # tolerations: []

  ## @param nodeSelector - object - optional
  ## Allow the DaemonSet to schedule on selected nodes
  ## Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/node-selection/
  #
  # nodeSelector: {}

  ## @param affinity - object - optional
  ## Allow the DaemonSet to schedule using affinity rules
  ## Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity
  #
  # affinity: {}

  ## @param updateStrategy - string - optional
  ## Allow the DaemonSet to perform a rolling update on helm update
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-daemon/update-daemon-set/
  #
  # updateStrategy: RollingUpdate

  ## @param priorityClassName - string - optional
  ## Sets PriorityClassName if defined.
  #
  # priorityClassName:

  ## @param podLabels - object - optional
  ## Sets podLabels if defined.
  #
  # podLabels: {}

  ## @param useConfigMap - boolean - optional
  #  Configures a configmap to provide the agent configuration
  #
  # useConfigMap: false

deployment:
  ## @param enabled - boolean - required
  ## Apart from DaemonSet, deploy Datadog agent pods and related service for
  ## applications that want to send custom metrics. Provides DogStasD service.
  #
  enabled: false

  ## @param replicas - integer - required
  ## If you want to use datadog.collectEvents, keep deployment.replicas set to 1.
  #
  replicas: 1

  ## @param affinity - object - required
  ## Affinity for pod assignment
  ## Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity
  #
  affinity: {}

  ## @param tolerations - array - required
  ## Tolerations for pod assignment
  ## Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/
  #
  tolerations: []

  ## @param dogstatsdNodePort - integer - optional
  ## If you're using a NodePort-type service and need a fixed port, set this parameter.
  #
  # dogstatsdNodePort: 8125

  ## @param traceNodePort - integer - optional
  ## If you're using a NodePort-type service and need a fixed port, set this parameter.
  #
  # traceNodePort: 8126

  ## @param service - object - required
  ##
  #
  service:
    type: ClusterIP
    annotations: {}

  ## @param priorityClassName - string - optional
  ## Sets PriorityClassName if defined.
  #
  # priorityClassName:

clusterchecksDeployment:

  ## @param enabled - boolean - required
  ## If true, deploys agent dedicated for running the Cluster Checks instead of running in the Daemonset's agents.
  ## ref: https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/autodiscovery/clusterchecks/
  #
  enabled: false

  rbac:
    ## @param dedicated - boolean - required
    ## If true, use a dedicated RBAC resource for the cluster checks agent(s)
    #
    dedicated: false
    ## @param serviceAccountName - string - required
    ## Ignored if rbac.create is true
    #
    serviceAccountName: default

  ## @param replicas - integer - required
  ## If you want to deploy the cluckerchecks agent in HA, keep at least clusterchecksDeployment.replicas set to 2.
  ## And increase the clusterchecksDeployment.replicas according to the number of Cluster Checks.
  #
  replicas: 2

  ## @param resources - object -required
  ## Datadog clusterchecks-agent resource requests and limits.
  #
  resources: {}
  # requests:
  #   cpu: 200m
  #   memory: 500Mi
  # limits:
  #   cpu: 200m
  #   memory: 500Mi

  ## @param affinity - object - optional
  ## Allow the ClusterChecks Deployment to schedule using affinity rules.
  ## By default, ClusterChecks Deployment Pods are forced to run on different Nodes.
  ## Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity
  #
  # affinity:

  ## @param nodeSelector - object - optional
  ## Allow the ClusterChecks Deploument to schedule on selected nodes
  ## Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/node-selection/
  #
  # nodeSelector: {}

  ## @param tolerations - array - required
  ## Tolerations for pod assignment
  ## Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/
  #
  # tolerations: []

  ## @param livenessProbe - object - optional
  ## Override the agent's liveness probe logic from the default:
  ## In case of issues with the probe, you can disable it with the
  ## following values, to allow easier investigating:
  #
  # livenessProbe:
  #   exec:
  #     command: ["/bin/true"]

  ## @param env - list of object - optional
  ## The dd-agent supports many environment variables
  ## ref: https://github.com/DataDog/datadog-agent/tree/master/Dockerfiles/agent#environment-variables
  #
  # env:
  #   - name: <ENV_VAR_NAME>
  #     value: <ENV_VAR_VALUE>
```

as you can see I expect my logs to be available at /app/logs/service.log and thats what Im supplying to my conf.d :

```
confd:
    conf.yaml: |-
      init_config:
      instances:
      logs:
        - type: "file"
          path: "/app/logs/service.log"
          service: nodejs
          source: nodejs
          sourcecategory: sourcecode
```

In my service, I use WinstonLogger using file transport with the JSON format.

```
transports: [
            new transports.File({
              winston.format.json(),
              filename: `${process.env.LOGS_PATH}/service.log`,
            }),
]
```

process.env.LOGS_PATH = '/app/logs'

After all, exploring my pod and tail -f my service.log in the expected /app/logs folder I see that the application actually writes the logs in a JSON format as expected.

My DataDog doesn't pick up the logs and they are not showing in the log section ..

NOTE:: I do not mount any volume to and from my service ..

What am I missing? 
Should I mount my local log to /var/log/pods/[service_name]/   ?

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is that you would have to mount the volume in both the app container and the agent container in order to make it available. It also means you have to find a place to store the log file before it gets picked up by the agent. Doing this for every container could become difficult to maintain and time consuming.

An alternative approach would be to instead send the logs to `stdout` and let the agent collect them with the Docker integration. Since you configured `logsConfigContainerCollectAll` to `true`, the agent is already configured to collect the logs from every container output, so configuring Winston to output to `stdout` should just work.

See: https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/docker/log/

Answer (score 2):

To support rochdev comment, here are a few code snippets to help out (if you do not opt in for the STDOUT method which should be simpler). This is only to mount the right volume inside the container agent.

On your app deployment, add:

```
   spec:
      containers:
      - name: your_nodejs_app
        ...
        volumeMounts:
          - name: abc
            mountPath: /app/logs
      volumes:
        - hostPath:
            path: /app/logs
          name: abc
```

And on your agent daemonset:

```
   spec:
      containers:
      - image: datadog/agent
        ...
        volumeMounts:
          ...
          - name: plop
            mountPath: /app/logs
      volumes:
        ...
        - hostPath:
            path: /app/logs/
          name: plop
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.
eventually, I did go for the STDOUT solution.
My problem was that my console wasn't printing JSON as I was expecting ( and the daemon set).
Once i fixed the logs issue the chart worked out of the box.
Thanks !!